# OSDev. __attribute__((interrupt)) can't work completely

Tags: c, gcc, interrupt, qemu, osdev

I am writing an OS. I want to use `__attribute__((interrupt))` to do some interrupt support(I copied a bunch of code from [PonchoOS](https://github.com/Absurdponcho/PonchoOS) to start).However, only Page Fault Detected and Double Fault Detected are valid,other interrupt don't work(such as keyboard and timer).

This is header:

```
#ifndef _KERNEL_INTERRUPTS_H_
#define _KERNEL_INTERRUPTS_H_
#include <stdint.h>

#define GP_FAULT 0xD
#define PAGE_FAULT 0xE
#define TIME_INTR 0x20
#define KERYBOARD_INTR 0x21
#define MOUSE_INTR 0x2C
#define PI_INTR 0x20
#define SOFT_INTR 0x80
#define DOUBLE_PAGE_FAULT 0x08

#define IDT_InterruptGate    0x8e
#define IDT_CallGate         0x8c
#define IDT_TrapGate         0x8f

#define PIC1_COMMAND 0x20
#define PIC1_DATA 0x21
#define PIC2_COMMAND 0xA0
#define PIC2_DATA 0xA1
#define PIC_EOI 0x20

#define ICW1_INIT 0x10
#define ICW1_ICW4 0x01
#define ICW4_8086 0x01

typedef struct _idtr {
    uint16_t limit;
    uint64_t offset;
} __attribute__((packed)) IDTR;

typedef struct _idt {
    uint16_t offset0;
    uint16_t selector;
    uint8_t zero;
    uint8_t type;
    uint16_t offset1;
    uint32_t offset2;
    uint32_t reserved;
} __attribute__((packed)) IDT;

void setIDTOffset(IDT* _idt, uint64_t offset);
uint64_t getIDTOffset(IDT* _idt);
void initializeInterrupts(void);
void setIRQ(uint8_t iqrn, void* handler, uint8_t typeAttributes, uint8_t selector);
void initializePIC(void);
void picEnd(void);

struct InterruptFrame;
__attribute__((interrupt)) void pageFaultHandler(struct InterruptFrame* Frame);
__attribute__((interrupt)) void timerHandler(struct InterruptFrame* Frame);
__attribute__((interrupt)) void doubleFaultHandler(struct InterruptFrame* Frame);
__attribute__((interrupt)) void gpFaultHandler(struct InterruptFrame* Frame);
__attribute__((interrupt)) void keyboardIntHandler(struct InterruptFrame* Frame);
__attribute__((interrupt)) void mouseIntHandler(struct InterruptFrame* Frame);
__attribute__((interrupt)) void pitIntHandler(struct InterruptFrame* Frame);

#endif /* _KERNEL_INTERRUPTS_H_ */
```

This is the implementation:

```
#include <interrupts.h>
#include <graphics.h>
#include <io.h>

IDT idt[256];
IDTR idtr;

void setIDTOffset(IDT* _idt, uint64_t offset) {
    _idt->offset0 = (uint16_t)(offset & 0xffff);
    _idt->offset1 = (uint16_t)((offset & 0xffff0000) >> 16);
    _idt->offset2 = (uint32_t)((offset & 0xffffffff00000000) >> 32);
}

uint64_t getIDTOffset(IDT* _idt) {
    uint64_t offset = 0;
    offset |= (uint64_t)_idt->offset0;
    offset |= (uint64_t)_idt->offset1 << 16;
    offset |= (uint64_t)_idt->offset2 << 32;
    return offset;
}

void initializeInterrupts(void) {
    idtr.limit = sizeof(IDT) * 256 - 1;
    idtr.offset = (uint64_t)idt;

    asm volatile("cli");
    setIRQ(PAGE_FAULT, (void*)pageFaultHandler, IDT_InterruptGate, 0x8);
    setIRQ(TIME_INTR, (void*)timerHandler, IDT_InterruptGate, 0x8);
    setIRQ(KERYBOARD_INTR, (void*)keyboardIntHandler, IDT_InterruptGate, 0x8);
    setIRQ(DOUBLE_PAGE_FAULT, (void*)doubleFaultHandler, IDT_InterruptGate, 0x8);
    setIRQ(GP_FAULT, (void*)gpFaultHandler, IDT_InterruptGate, 0x8);
    setIRQ(MOUSE_INTR, (void*)mouseIntHandler, IDT_InterruptGate, 0x8);
    setIRQ(PI_INTR, (void*)pitIntHandler, IDT_InterruptGate, 0x8);
    asm ("lidt %0" : : "m" (idtr));
    asm volatile("sti");
    initializePIC();
}

void setIRQ(uint8_t iqrn, void* handler, uint8_t typeAttributes, uint8_t selector) {
    setIDTOffset(&idt[iqrn], (uint64_t)handler);
    idt[iqrn].type = typeAttributes;
    idt[iqrn].selector = selector;
    idt[iqrn].zero = 0;
    idt[iqrn].reserved = 0;
}

void initializePIC(void) {
    uint8_t a1, a2;
    a1 = inb(PIC1_DATA);
    ioWait();
    a2 = inb(PIC2_DATA);
    ioWait();

    outb(PIC1_COMMAND, ICW1_INIT | ICW1_ICW4);
    ioWait();
    outb(PIC2_COMMAND, ICW1_INIT | ICW1_ICW4);
    ioWait;

    outb(PIC1_DATA, 0x20);
    ioWait();
    outb(PIC2_DATA, 0x28);
    ioWait();

    outb(PIC1_DATA, 4);
    ioWait();
    outb(PIC2_DATA, 2);
    ioWait();

    outb(PIC1_DATA, ICW4_8086);
    ioWait();
    outb(PIC2_DATA, ICW4_8086);
    ioWait();

    outb(PIC1_DATA, a1);
    ioWait();
    outb(PIC2_DATA, a2);
}

void picEnd(void){
    outb(PIC2_COMMAND, PIC_EOI);
    outb(PIC1_COMMAND, PIC_EOI);
}

__attribute__((interrupt)) void pageFaultHandler(struct InterruptFrame* Frame) {
    clear();
    debugPrint("Page Fault Detected");
    while(1);
}

__attribute__((interrupt)) void timerHandler(struct InterruptFrame* Frame) {
    debugPrint("timer\n");
    picEnd();
}

__attribute__((interrupt)) void doubleFaultHandler(struct InterruptFrame* Frame) {
    clear();
    debugPrint("Double Fault Detected");
    while(1);
}

__attribute__((interrupt)) void gpFaultHandler(struct InterruptFrame* Frame) {
    clear();
    debugPrint("General Protection Fault Detected");
    while(1);
}

__attribute__((interrupt)) void keyboardIntHandler(struct InterruptFrame* Frame) {
    clear();
    debugPrint("Pressed");
    uint8_t scanCode = inb(0x60);
    picEnd();
}

__attribute__((interrupt)) void mouseIntHandler(struct InterruptFrame* Frame) {

}

__attribute__((interrupt)) void pitIntHandler(struct InterruptFrame* Frame) {

}
```

This is my [github](https://github.com/qgmzhnwww/wwt).

I use "asm (" int $0x21 ")" to manually trigger the keyboard interrupt. Data can be read through port 0x60.

I'm using x86_64-elf-gcc to build and QEMU to run the kerne.How do I solve this problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: What compiler are you using? `__attribute__((interrupt))` isn't standard [or supported] on most compilers. For the system I'm familiar with (Xilinx FPGA with microblaze), there was a similar attribute to force the function to have prolog/epilog code that pushed/popped the processor registers (and do the equiv. of `iret` on return). But, this was specific to their compiler. The usual for x86, is to point the IDT entry to an assembler function that did all that and then indexed into a function call table to get the address of the C function to call. You may want to look at `entry_*.S` in linux

Comment: @CraigEstey : The interrupt attribute has been around in the x86/x86-64 gcc builds for a while now (gcc since 7.0 and clang since about 9.0), although the limitation that you can't reliably determine the value of any given register at the time the interrupt occurs can make it less useful. I generally stick with assembly stubs that call a regular _C_ function.

Comment: Putting your own project in github so we can try your own code would be preferable. The PonchoOS which you base it on doesn't help us solve your problem.

Comment: @MichaelPetch We're [i.e. I'm ;-)] never too old to learn new things. It's fine for a _simple_ bare metal ISR impl. I was thinking about _not_ knowing the interrupt frame format [reliably] without a `gcc` provided `.h` file. The stub approach is what I was suggesting, so we're in agreement. OP _could_ look at the disassembly and "divine" the frame. But, IMO, it's a bit hacky. It's difficult if we want to implement a task/process switch from within an ISR (e.g. time slice on timer interrupt). When I did the microblaze impl, the tasks were cooperative "coroutines", so no switch in an ISR

Comment: An observation. enabling interrupts before reprogramming the PICs couid see you getting external interrupts on top of the exceptions which  might not work as expected.

Comment: @MichaelPetch  Thank you for your suggestion. This is my GitHub [My OS](https://github.com/qgmzhnwww/wwt)

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks for your help.I'm using x86_64-elf-gcc  for compilation.As far as I know, it should support. IDT  is usually assembly, but I want to use `__attribute__((interrupt))`.

Comment: @wwt I tried doing the same (using gcc attributes) for my own toy kernel. It might seem "hacky" to not use it but it is the contrary. It is actually less hacky to use an assembly stub to do this kind of thing. Otherwise, it leads to very specific problems that cannot be fixed properly.

Comment: @user123 Thank you for your reply. I have tried to use assembly, but interrupts cannot be triggered. I guess interrupts do not work on QEMU. Do you have any better suggestions?

Comment: Interrupts work on QEMU, the fault will be in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your reply.Just turn on all interrupts.

```
outb(PIC1_DATA, 0x0); // enable all interrupt
ioWait();
outb(PIC2_DATA, 0x0);
ioWait();
```